# Is there a way to convert C# HttpClient to curl?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, curl, .net-core, httpclient

**Imagine you are making a HTTP request for example (though it could be any http call):**

```
string baseurl = LocalConfigKey.BaseUrl;
string geturl = string.Format("{0}leo-platform-api/api/v1/Orchestrator/Endpoint", baseurl);

var response = string.Empty;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", LocalConfigKey.APIMSubscriptionKey);
    HttpResponseMessage result = httpClient.GetAsync(geturl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to generate curl out of this request that can be logged in a db etc ?

Comment: Do you mean automagically convert _any_ http client setup to a cURL, or this very specific case?

Comment: @Jamiec Any http client setup to a cURL

Comment: An HTTP  Request consists of 1) URL 2) HTTP Header (optional) 3) HTTP Body.  The CURL is the data inside the body.

Comment: @jdweng Er, no it isn't at all. cURL is the URL, body, headers etc. It's the entire request

Comment: @jdweng what I am looking for is a way to programmatically translate the HttpClient request setup to a bash curl. Just like chrome lets you copy url from the networks tab

Comment: Swagger does this, you could look at how they do it.

Comment: @DavidG : Curl is just a tool for sending the REQUST.  See : https://www.keycdn.com/support/popular-curl-examples?force_isolation=true

Comment: CURL is just a tool.   The output from CURL and HTTPClient request are the same.

Comment: @jdweng I know exactly what it is, I use it regularly. But you said "CURL is the data inside the body" which is not true.

Comment: @SamuraiJack, can you show the expected result from the example?

Comment: I don't think a ready/easy solution exist. You will need to inject a custom `HttpClientHandler` in the `HttpClient` to catch all requests, transform in CURL and store in DB. If you have a solution, I will be grateful if you share it.

Comment: this might help get you started: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-code-generators/blob/develop/codegens/curl/lib/index.js

Answer (score 4):

You can use this package to convert `HTTPClient` to curl:

First, install the NuGet package:

`dotnet add package HttpClientToCurl`

Example:

***1*. Declare request requirements:**

```
string requestBody = @"{ ""name"" : ""amin"",""requestId"" : ""10001000"",""amount"":10000 }";
string requestUri = "api/test";
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);
httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1213");
```

***2*. Get curl from the request in 3 ways:**

```
string curlScript = httpClient.GenerateCurlInString(httpRequestMessage); //Put into a variable

httpClient.GenerateCurlInConsole(httpRequestMessage); //Show in the console

httpClient.GenerateCurlInFile(httpRequestMessage); //Write in a file
```

***3.* HTTP call:**

```
await client.PostAsync(requestUri, httpRequestMessage.Content);
```

**[To get more information see the repo GitHub docs](https://github.com/amingolmahalle/HttpClientToCurlGenerator)**

Comment: There is a small limitation, though, the BaseAddress needs to be set, using absolute paths in requests is not supported.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik You can create an issue on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/amingolmahalle/HttpClientToCurlGenerator

Comment: A useful article for HttpClientToCurl extension: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-generate-curl-script-of-the-httpclient-in-net/